# How can I add transparent space around a gif?

Tags: image, imagemagick, animated-gif

I need to take a spinner gif and add text to it, but the text needs to be under the spinner animation, below the border of the current image.

Is there a command to add transparent space around an image with Imagemagick? Alternatively, is there a free online tool to achieve the same result?

I tried the following, but it creates a very jittery and unusable image:

```
convert spinner.gif -background none -gravity north -extent 400x200 new_spinner.gif
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a working solution, thanks to a combination of [jimmetry's answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14036766/2441263) and [this imagemagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#extent):

```
convert spinner.gif -coalesce -repage 0x0 -background none -gravity north -extent 400x200 +repage new_spinner.gif
```

Comment: Thank you for this command. Searched a lot on internet but none of the websites let me add lefr/right padding but this one worked like a charm.